# Failed to download an bacpac file

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to download a .bacpac file from Microsoft Azure Storage, but it indicates that there is an error: An incorrect number of bytes was read from the connection. The connection may have been closed.

Please, How can I solve this problem? 
Is there any other way to download files from Azure Storage?

Comment: What method you were using to perform the download?

Comment: That error may be related to a transient error. Retry again using azcopy: AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /S